# Fixing border to UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

I am taking text to `UILabel` which is inside a `UItableViewCell`(label text is coming from webData-so it varies in size).

I want to give a border for my label, which should fit the text width and height. I have created one, but it's not looking good.
Help me to improve my code.

**Also is there any way to get border with rounded corners ? **

Hey I am getting text inside the border like this, and the corners are not so rounded:

[image]

```
UILabel *cmntBoxlbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(58, 23, 250, 60)];
cmntBoxlbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
cmntBoxlbl.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
cmntBoxlbl.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",@"  ",[[self.DtlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"comment"],@" "];
cmntBoxlbl.text = text;



cmntBoxlbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
cmntBoxlbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
[cmntBoxlbl setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [text sizeWithFont:cmntBoxlbl.font
                            constrainedToSize:cmntBoxlbl.frame.size
                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CGRect newFrame = cmntBoxlbl.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
cmntBoxlbl.frame = newFrame;
cmntBoxlbl.numberOfLines = 0;
[cmntBoxlbl sizeToFit];
[cell addSubview:cmntBoxlbl];
```

Comment: oh you again...thanks

issue is that,text inside the border is disorder text is coming
i have posted the screen shot below

And also i have to make rounded corners

Comment: +1 for a well explained question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rounded corner set.

```
[cmntBoxlbl.layer setCornerRadius:15];
```

Also add the `QuartzCore` framework and import the header:

`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Answer (score 3):

*also is there any way to get border with rounded corners ?? *

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
label.layer.borderWidth = 3;
label.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
label.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```